# Default values in rest resources instead of POST/PUT null

Tags: rest

For some rest resource, there are two fields connected. There is, if one field is POST/PUT it gets the value of the other field.

In this example we have a amount and amountWithVat(with tax or Value Added Tax). 
If you POST or PUT a null for amountWithVat the default value will be from amount.

```
Example 1
POST
amount=150
amountWithVAT=null
GET
amount=150
amountWithVAT=150

Example 2
POST
amount=150
amountWithVAT=170
GET
amount=150
amountWithVAT=170
PUT
amount=200
amountWithVAT=null
GET
amount=200
amountWithVAT=200
```

For me this does not feel intuitive, but from the view of a front end developer this could make sense. Personally I would rather enforce this by forbidding POST/PUT nulls.

Are there any guidelines or best practices which go against this?

Comment: Well this does raise some questions. Where is the default value here? What would have happened if you'd put a GET immediately after the POST in example 2? Why do the nulls only go in the Vat? What the hecks a Vat? I can't tell if it's the design or the examples that aren't intuitive.

Comment: @CandiedOrange I added the details you asked for in the question. So amountWithVat gets the default value of amount if omitted. Vat is Value Added Tax.

Comment: Pro tip:  capitalize abbreviations. Or your maintenance programmer will find you and dunk you in a vat of acid.

Comment: @CandiedOrange Even when they are longer then 2 characters? Is this a special rest convention I am not aware of? Typically in .net 3+ abbreviations are pascal. IO, Xml, Html etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on who plans to use the service I would say the guideline that this goes against is that it is not self documenting. If I were to

```
POST
amount=150
```

for the first time I would expect

```
GET
amount=150
amountVAT=null
```

Now if there is a requirement that says amountVAT can't be null, I think the best solution would be to notify the consumer

```
POST
amount=150
Response:
400: Bad Request
message: amountVAT can not be null / blank
```

That way the consumer is informed that amountVAT is required and can decide for themselves if they want to set it to the same as amount, or a different value.

Comment: And when the lawsuits start because someone couldn't tell if they are supposed add amount to amountVAT, or if the server adds them, your defense will be?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the premise. If the users are required to define the value for amountVAT, but don't put the right value in, they made a mistake, yes? If they want logic that says 'amountVAT cannot be less then amount' then that would be a constraint to add. And we could return that message with Bad Request. I'm not sure what 'if they are supposed add amount to amountVAT' means. But I also don't know what amountVAT is, so I wouldn't know how it is derived.

Comment: That's my point. You can't fix this with validation. You fix this with a better name then "amount". Self documenting, remember?